# How can I use `new this` within a non-static getter?

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, instance, getter

I am trying to create a new instance of the parent class from within static and regular getters. This works for static getters but doesn't work for regular ones.

```
class Example {
  static get clone() {
    return new this();
  }
  get clone() {
    return new this();
  }
}
```

Where as using `Example` over `this` works but causes an inability to extend from this class.

```
class Example {
  static get clone() {
    return new Example();
  }
  get clone() {
    return new Example();
  }
}
```

How can I use `new this` within a non-static getter?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for this:

```
class Example {
  static get clone() {
    return new this();
  }
  get clone() {
    const copy = new (this.constructor as any)();
    Object.assign(copy, this);
    return copy;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Foo extends Example {}

console.log(
    Example.clone,
    new Example().clone,
    Foo.clone,
    new Foo().clone
)
```

Comment: Just needs `return copy as this`